# Get-PnPFolderItem not returning file versions from SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am working on the script that would check SharePoint site for files with lots of versions, so I am using Get-PnPFolderItem command to list files, one of the properties of which is 'Versions' , but for some reason its empty.
Any idea why it could be happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For files got by this cmdlet, we need to use clientContext to load the file version property.

Demo:

```
$ctx = Get-PnPContext

$items=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "lib"

$ctx.Load($items[5].Versions)

$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try it.     
I have been using Get-PnPFileVersion and it works until it gets any file with few hundreds versions and then I am getting "The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes."  - Do you know if in your solution it just get versions info or it actually downloads all versions, as in Get-PnPFileVersion?

Comment: No, I did not test with a file having so many versions.